# Sorting dataframe and creating new columns based on the rank of element

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
                  {
                   'id': [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2,2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3],
                   'name': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','A', 'B','C', 'D', 'A', 'B','C', 'D'], 
                   'Value': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 0, 2, 4, 6, 3, 5]
                  },
                  columns=['name','id','Value'])`
```

I can sort the data using id and value as shown below:

```
df.sort_values(['id','Value'],ascending = [True,False])
```

The table that I print will be appearing as follow:

```
  name   id   Value
    D      1      4
    C      1      3
    B      1      2
    A      1      1
    B      2      6
    A      2      5
    D      2      2
    C      2      0
    B      3      6
    D      3      5
    A      3      4
    C      3      3
```

I would like to create 4 new columns  **(Rank1, Rank2, Rank3, Rank4)** if element in the column **name** is highest value, the column **Rank1** will be assign as **1** else **0**. if  element in the column **name** is second highest value, he column **Rank2** will be assign as **1** else **0**.
Same for Rank3 and Rank4.

How could I do that?

Thanks.

Zep

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use:

```
df = df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1)).add_prefix('Rank'))
print (df)
   name  id  Value  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4
3     D   1      4      1      0      0      0
2     C   1      3      0      1      0      0
1     B   1      2      0      0      1      0
0     A   1      1      0      0      0      1
5     B   2      6      1      0      0      0
4     A   2      5      0      1      0      0
7     D   2      2      0      0      1      0
6     C   2      0      0      0      0      1
9     B   3      6      1      0      0      0
11    D   3      5      0      1      0      0
8     A   3      4      0      0      1      0
10    C   3      3      0      0      0      1
```

**Details**:

For count per groups use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html), then add `1`:

```
print (df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1))
3     1
2     2
1     3
0     4
5     1
4     2
7     3
6     4
9     1
11    2
8     3
10    4
dtype: int64
```

For indicator columns use [`get_dumes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) with [`add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
print (pd.get_dummies(df.groupby('id').cumcount().add(1)).add_prefix('Rank'))
    Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4
3       1      0      0      0
2       0      1      0      0
1       0      0      1      0
0       0      0      0      1
5       1      0      0      0
4       0      1      0      0
7       0      0      1      0
6       0      0      0      1
9       1      0      0      0
11      0      1      0      0
8       0      0      1      0
10      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thanks Jezrael. Really appreciate your help and it saves a lot on my time :)

Answer (score 2):

This does not require a prior sort

```
df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        df.groupby('id').Value.apply(np.argsort).rsub(4)
    ).add_prefix('Rank')
)

   name  id  Value  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4
0     D   1      4      1      0      0      0
1     C   1      3      0      1      0      0
2     B   1      2      0      0      1      0
3     A   1      1      0      0      0      1
4     B   2      6      1      0      0      0
5     A   2      5      0      1      0      0
6     D   2      2      0      0      1      0
7     C   2      0      0      0      0      1
8     B   3      6      1      0      0      0
9     D   3      5      0      1      0      0
10    A   3      4      0      0      1      0
11    C   3      3      0      0      0      1
```

---

More dynamic

```
df.join(
    pd.get_dummies(
        df.groupby('id').Value.apply(lambda x: len(x) - np.argsort(x))
    ).add_prefix('Rank')
)

   name  id  Value  Rank1  Rank2  Rank3  Rank4
0     D   1      4      1      0      0      0
1     C   1      3      0      1      0      0
2     B   1      2      0      0      1      0
3     A   1      1      0      0      0      1
4     B   2      6      1      0      0      0
5     A   2      5      0      1      0      0
6     D   2      2      0      0      1      0
7     C   2      0      0      0      0      1
8     B   3      6      1      0      0      0
9     D   3      5      0      1      0      0
10    A   3      4      0      0      1      0
11    C   3      3      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: Thanks piRSquared

Comment: hmmm, if dont use @ I get no notification :)

Comment: No, but I explain reason if you will be curious get no reaction for commnet  ;)

Comment: what about `df.join(pd.get_dummies(df.groupby("id")["Value"].rank().astype(int)).add_prefix("Rank"))`

Comment: @Lambda you need to make sure to use method=first